# Issue with importing in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have two python files:

one.py

```
import numpy as np
```

two.py

```
from one import *
print(np.ones(5))
```

When I run two.py in colab using the command

```
!python two.py
```

I get the error that np is not defined. How do I solve this? 
My actual situation is a bit more complex, but the gist of it is as I have explained above. Also, both the files have been uploaded to google drive and are under the same folder.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are trying to import libraries specified in one.py by calling two.py. If so, the error seems to be that the syntax 'from X import Y' is specific to libraries, so wouldn't you want two.py to run the contents of one.py as a bash script?

Comment: Actually, when I try to run the above on my Linux based system, it runs without any problem. The problem occurs only in colab.

Comment: Oh, ok. How are you defining the path in Colab?

Comment: Strange. I did the procedure again exactly and It worked. The previous time it didn't. Could it be that restarting the colab session or something with the drive that made it work this time around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me; I suspect you simplified away a salient detail from your actual situation.
[image]